# Unable to install SQL Server 2014 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2014

I'm running into problems installation SQL Server 2014 Developer edition on Windows 7 64-bit; I receive a message that the installation completed with the following errors:
    Feature: Database Engine Services (Status: Failed)
    Feature: Data Quality Services (Status: Failed)
    Feature: Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search (Status: Failed)
    Feature: SQL Server Replication (Status: Failed)
    Feature: Reporting Services - Native (Status: Failed)

I estimate that I've uninstalled and re-installed SQL Server 2014 at least three times. During each uninstall, I removed all SQL Server references from the system using "Revo Uninstaller". Additionally, I installed the updated described in "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821#". During the last install, I executed the "setup.exe" file as an administrator; the installation failed with the same issues after the update and while running "setup.exe" as an administrator. Finally, I followed the instructions described in "[Repair/Remove/Install processes for SQL Server 2012 Express get stuck or hung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266590/repair-remove-install-processes-for-sql-server-2012-express-get-stuck-or-hung)":

Solution 1:
- Stop the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" & "SQL Server VSS Writer" services and set their Startup Type to "Manual".
- Restart the PC.
- Run the repair process.
- Change the Startup Type back to "Automatic" and restart the services.

Solution 2:
- Stop the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" & "SQL Server VSS Writer" services and set their Startup Type to "Disabled".
- Restart the PC.
- Run the Remove process to uninstall SQL Server Express entirely (instance + shared components).
- Restart the PC again.
- [Optional] Run your favorite registry cleaner such as CCleaner.
- Install SQL Server Express (unless your goal was just to uninstall it).

```
Output from the last installation attempt is listed below:
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578302
  Start time:                    2016-04-18 09:34:00
  End time:                      2016-04-18 09:36:21
  Requested action:              Repair

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for RS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  *******
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Developer Edition    12.0.2000.8     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality Services                    1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER             Analysis Services                        1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER          MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Developer Edition    12.1.4100.1     No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         F:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Repair
  AGTDOMAINGROUP:                <empty>
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160418_093359\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  ENU:                           true
  FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          <empty>
  FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160418_093359\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

  Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Reporting Services
  Component error code:          0x84B40002
  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'RS_Server_Adv' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160418_093359\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Help?!?!?!?!?!?!?
```